# Explanation of fields

Tags: c#, facebook, search, facebook-graph-api

I am looking at the facebook search api, but I have difficulties with the object returned.

I am using the following code:

```
 Dictionary<string, object> searchParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
 searchParams.Add("q", "cookie");
 searchParams.Add("type", "post");

 var facebookClient = new Facebook.FacebookClient();
 dynamic content = facebookClient.Get("/search", searchParams );
```

But it seems like the dynamic data returned form the query is very obscure. Sometimes the content.data[..].link returns the link to the post, other times it returns a link to an image,  or a youtube video.

Are there any guide to what to expect from the results, so I can distinguise if a link is to the post, image or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really look on `type` field in every search result which specify what object type it is, and look on documentation for [searching](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#searching) (to know which types is supported in results) and objects fields for every object (like [`photo`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/), [`page`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/), [`post`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/), etc...) since every object may have different meaning of the same field...

Comment: Thanks, this was excately the documentation I was looking for.